# Сдвинулась кнопка на странице

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем доброго времени суток. Сдвинулась кнопка поиска, скриншот прилагаеться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка должна быть на уровне строки поиска. В верстке не силен. Код самого блока представлен ниже:

```css
 @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&subset=cyrillic'
  body{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .top{
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .top-bl{
    background: #bebebe;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .top-bl .cart{
    float: right;
  }
  #sidebar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li{
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li.selected{
    background: #0095ff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li.selected a{
    color: white;
  }
  .items{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .item{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .item a img{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .product-detail{
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .price{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .product-detail h2{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  form.add{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  form.add label{
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #id_quantity{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  form.add input[type="submit"]{
    background: #2a6496;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
  }
  .table-cart{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .cart-img{
    width: 10%;
  }
  th, td{
    padding: 5px;
  }
  thead{
    background: #2a6496;
    color: white;
  }
  .btn{
    background: #2a6496;
    color: white;
  }
  .btn-light{
    background: #808080;
  }
  .order-info h2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .order-form{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .order-form label{
    display: block;
  }
  .order-form input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
  <section id="header">
<div class="top container">
  Онлайн магазин "Гитарист"
</div>
<div class="top-bl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <a class="btn btn-large" href="/">Главная</a>
          <a class="btn btn-large" href="/">Доставка</a>
          <a class="btn btn-large" href="/">О нас</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'shop:ProductSearch' %}" class="pull-down  navbar-search">
                <input style="width: auto; display: inline-block" class="form-control"  name="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Поиск..." >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" type="button">Поиск</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="cart">
              {% with total_items=cart|length %}
                {% if cart|length > 0 %}
                  Ваша корзина:
                  <a href="{% url "cart:CartDetail" %}">
                    {{ total_items }} тов. {{ cart.get_total_price }} грн.
                  </a>
                {% else %}
                  Корзина пустая
                {% endif %}
              {% endwith %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
  <section id="content row" class="container">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проблема определённо в css стилях. Если их убрать, всё работает нормально. Нужен код `pull-down`, `navbar-search`, `form-control`, `btn` и `btn-large`.

Comment: Причиной скорее всего являются либо `clear: both;`, либо `display: block;` в `css`. По тем данным, что вы предоставили - это сказать невозможно.

Comment: @Egor, добавил css файл и полный базовыйhtml от которого все наследуеться.

Answer (score 2):

Вы предоставили не тот `css` файл. В нём нет стилей, которые указаны в форме и элементах. Если вы нажмёте на кнопку `Выполнить код` ниже, то увидите, что элементы расположены в одной строке, но стиль у них отличается от той картинки, что вы приложили к вопросу. Это потому, что в файле стилей, который вы скинули нет `pull-down`, `navbar-search`, `form-control` и `btn-large`. Есть только на `btn`.

```css
 @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&subset=cyrillic'
  body{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .top{
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .top-bl{
    background: #bebebe;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .top-bl .cart{
    float: right;
  }
  #sidebar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li{
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li.selected{
    background: #0095ff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li.selected a{
    color: white;
  }
  .items{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .item{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .item a img{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .product-detail{
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .price{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .product-detail h2{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  form.add{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  form.add label{
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #id_quantity{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  form.add input[type="submit"]{
    background: #2a6496;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
  }
  .table-cart{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .cart-img{
    width: 10%;
  }
  th, td{
    padding: 5px;
  }
  thead{
    background: #2a6496;
    color: white;
  }
  .btn{
    background: #2a6496;
    color: white;
  }
  .btn-light{
    background: #808080;
  }
  .order-info h2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .order-form{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .order-form label{
    display: block;
  }
  .order-form input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

```html
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'shop:ProductSearch' %}" class="pull-down  navbar-search">
   <input style="width: auto; display: inline-block" class="form-control"  name="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Поиск..." >
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" type="button">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Вот еще нашел bootstrap.min.css, залил на pastebin. https://pastebin.com/tLYU0tQr

Comment: Этот файл со стилями я уже просмотрел давно. В нём нет `pull-down`, `navbar-search`, `form-control` и `btn-large`. У вас есть возможность залить проект на хостинг (любой), чтобы можно было видеть сайт в том виде, в котором вы его видите?

Comment: вот линк https://github.com/freedomwarrior/myshop-fromhell

Comment: Я имел ввиду не исходники, а запущенный сайт, где кнопка уползла вниз. Посмотрел проект на гите. Сложно. В нём нет стилей. Как вы сделали ту фотографию, которую прикрепили к вопросу? Я хочу вам помочь, но всё больше не понимаю =(

Comment: ну как, на локалхосте запустил:)

Comment: Если вы всё ещё не смогли решить вашу проблему, готов помочь вам в индивидуальном порядке. Могу подключиться к вашему компьютеру через `teamviewer`, чтобы увидеть ваш сайт на локалхосте и мы вместе попробуем решить ваш вопрос.